# Using apply to find max in a data frame with missing values and strings

Tags: r, max, apply, na

I have the following data set:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
     ID N1 N2 N3 N4
      1 2 3 4 5
     11 NA -12 14 55
     21 12 SON 34 14"))
```

I want to find out what is the max entry in each row. This would be, for example, 5 in the first row. Obviously, the situation is more complicated because of missing values ('NA') and a string ('SON').

I first tried the following command:

```
df$Result<-apply(df,1, max, na.rm= TRUE)
```

The results are [5,55, SON]! Not what I wanted. I therefore then tried:

```
checkd<- function(x) if(is.integer(x)== TRUE)max(x)
df$Result<-apply(df,1, checkd)
```

Funnily, it removed the last column `df$Result`. Does anyone know what did I do wrong? Also, what would be the solution to my problem?

Also, of I try the following code:

```
checkd<- function(x) if(is.integer(x)== TRUE)max(x)
df$Result<-apply(df,1, checkd, na.rm= TRUE)
```

it gives me `Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)`! Why is that? My function `checkd` does generally not seem to cause any problems to R. Why does R reject `na.rm= TRUE` when I use `checkd` but not when I use `max` in apply?

Thanks,

Dom

Comment: Try `apply(as.matrix(data.frame(lapply(df,as.numeric))),1,max,na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the points of using a data frame is that everything in a column must have the same class. If you want to treat your data as numeric, then run `as.numeric()` on each column and the strings, like `"SON"`, will be converted to `NA`.

Data frames are also focused on column-wise operations. If you want to go row-wise, a `matrix` probably makes more sense:

```
mat = sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
# as.numeric(as.character()) is necessary when starting with a factor
mat
#      ID N1  N2 N3 N4
# [1,]  1  2   3  4  5
# [2,] 11 NA -12 14 55
# [3,] 21 12  NA 34 14

apply(mat, 1, max, na.rm = T)
# [1]  5 55 34
```

> Why does R reject `na.rm= TRUE` when I use `checkd` but not when I use `max` in `apply`

After the first three arguments, (`X`, `MARGIN`, `FUN`), `apply` just passes arguments on through to the function you pass to `FUN`. If you look at the help for `?max`, you'll see that it is defined to take an argument called `na.rm`. Your definition for `checkd` has no such argument. If you want to add an `na.rm` argument to your function, you could do it like this:

```
checkd <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) if(is.integer(x)) max(x, na.rm = na.rm)
# or even this
checkd <- function(x, ...) if(is.integer(x)) max(x, ...)
```

Note that this function probably doesn't do what you want - it checks to see if the vector you give it - a whole row in your example - consists only of integers, and if so it will return the max. Since a vector can only have one type, if you have any non-integer in there, `is.integer(x)` will be false and the the max won't be calculated.

I also deleted your `== TRUE`, which doesn't do anything.

Comment: thanks! That is really useful! Just a quick follow-up question. I played around with `as.numeric`! I happened to notice that it turns the third column `3 -12 SON` into the following numerical values `2 1 3`! My question why does it not translate `3` into `3` but into `2` and `-12` not into `-12` but into `1` etc. If I wanted to do this, what would be the way? Anyway, thanks so much for your explanations. Super useful!

Comment: You probably have a factor to start with. See edits. And [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/903061) for more details.